# Ubuntu 14.04 shutdown on lid close

Tags: 14.04, systemd

I am trying to make my laptop shutdown on lid close - however it completely refuses to.

I have etc/systemd/logind.conf as follows:

HandleLidSwitch=poweroff
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes

On lid close it simply locks the screen. 
In battery settings I have "Do nothing" on lid close.

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just set that graphically, in settings?

Comment: no you cannot do that in settings

Comment: Sorry. Did you restart after you changed those options? I know it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below to open the configuration file via gedit editor:

sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
Replace gedit with vi or other text editor if you’re on Server edition.

2. Find out the line #HandleLidSwitch=suspend, remove the # and change it to:

> HandleLidSwitch=poweroff to shutdown computer when lid is closed
>   HandleLidSwitch=hibernate to hibernate computer when lid is closed
>   HandleLidSwitch=ignore to do nothing

3. Save the file and restart the service or just restart your laptop to apply changes.

> sudo restart systemd-logind

Comment: I am not sure you read the question - I did exactly that, and wrote in my question, yet it does not work